# Creating a new "int64" data type in c++ having values 0 to 63

Tags: c++, int, typedef

How can we create new data type of specified range in c++?
I know it can be declared like

```
    struct int64
    {
            unsigned a:6;
    } A;
```

But is there any way we can do it using "typedef" because using structure for just single variable is not good. 
And also in this we have to type code like

```
    cout<<A.a;
```

Thanks in advance........

Comment: I would recommend against using `int64` for this, regardless.

Comment: What are you hoping to gain with such a data type?

Comment: I feel like `struct int2_5` would be more fitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct unsigned6{
    unsigned value:6;
    operator unsigned()const{return value;}
    unsigned6()=default;
    unsigned6(const unsigned6&)=default;
    unsigned6(unsigned val):value(val){}
};

#include <iostream>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, unsigned6 &out){
    unsigned input;
    stream>>input;
    out=input;
    return stream;
}
```

//Usage is similiar to `unsigned`:

```
int main(){
    unsigned6 A(42);
    std::cout<<A<<'\n';
    std::cin >>A;
    std::cout<<A<<'\n';
}
```

I can imagine one thing you can't do with type wrote like this, and I can't fix it: you can't implicitly cast the type's object to `unsigned&` - I mean:

```
void foo(unsigned&);
foo(unsigned6() ); //won't compile
```